# stock query not show exact result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use this query to maintain my stock but its not show exact result

```
select p.Product_Name Product
      ,isnull(sum(d.qty),0) Purchase_Qty
      ,isnull(sum(i.qty),0) Issue_Qty
      ,(isnull(sum(d.qty),0)-isnull(sum(i.qty),0)) InStock
from purchase_dtl d 
left join issue_dpt i on i.Product_ID=d.Product_ID
right join product p on p.id = d.Product_ID
group by Product_Name
```

**Query result**

```
Product | Purchase_Qty | Issue_Qty | InStock
---------------------------------------------
Pen           1000          300        700
Books         4000         1000       3000
```

**My exact purchase qty**

```
Product | Purchase_Qty
----------------------
Pen           500
Books        2000
```

**My exact issue qty**

```
Product | Issue_Qty
-------------------
Pen          300
Books       1000
```

Please help me to solve my problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.Product_Name Product
      , p.Purchase_Qty
      , isnull(sum(i.qty),0) Issue_Qty
      , p.Purchase_Qty-isnull(sum(i.qty),0) InStock
from (select p.id, p.Product_Name, isnull(sum(d.qty),0) Purchase_Qty      
      from product p left join purchase_dtl d on p.id = d.Product_ID
      group by p.id, p.Product_Name) p
      left join issue_dpt i on i.Product_ID = p.id
group by Product_Name, p.Purchase_Qty
```

I suppose joining `purchase_dtl` and `issue_dpt` gives you some extra rows for `Purchase_Qty`

Join `product` with `purchase_dtl` first to calculate the aggregate data and then join again with `issue_dpt`

Comment: Can You help me in one more query?

Comment: @James Walker Ok, please create a question

Comment: I post my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342363/accounts-ledger-query-in-sql) Kindly help me Sir

Comment: @James Walker Check TomTom's answer. Your structure is really weak, that's why you need so many groupings. Where are you using it? Or is it kind of homework?

Comment: Can you please tell me correct structure? yes this is my assignment.