# Accounts Ledger query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query which maintain my accounts ledger

Here is my tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts](
    [Account_ID] [int] primary key,
    [Account_Name] [nvarchar](80),
    [Account_Type] [nvarchar](15))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Purchase_Invoice](
    [Purchase_ID] [int] primary key,
    [Purchase_Date] [datetime],
    [Account_ID] [int],
    [Purchase_SalesTax] [int],
    [Purchase_ExtraTax] [int],
    [Purchase_FutherTax] [int],
    [Purchase_Billno] [nvarchar](50),
    [Purchase_Amount] [decimal](9, 2))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sale_Invoice](
    [Invoice_ID] [int] primary key,
    [Invoice_Date] [datetime],
    [Account_ID] [int],
    [Invoice_SalesTax] [int],
    [Invoice_ExtraTax] [int],
    [Invoice_FurtherTax] [int],
    [Invoice_Amount] [decimal](10, 2))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transection](
    [Trans_ID] [int] primary key,
    [Trans_Date] [datetime],
    [Trans_Desc] [nvarchar](200))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DebitCredit](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Trans_ID] [int],
    [Account_ID] [int],
    [Amount] [decimal](9, 2),
    [Status] [varchar](5))

Insert into Accounts values(1,'Alicia', 'Customer')
Insert into Accounts values(2,'Mike', 'Supplier')
Insert into Accounts values(3,'AbcBank', 'Bank')

Insert into Purchase_Invoice values (1,'12/7/2014',2,0,0,0,'1254',5000)--Payment Debit in Supplier Mike Account

Insert into Sale_Invoice values (1,'12/7/2014',1,0,0,0,1500) --Payment Credit in Customer Alicia Account

Insert into Transection values (1,'12/7/2014','Payment Recevie From Customer')
insert into DebitCredit values (1,1,1500,'DB')--Payment Debit in Customer Alicia Account
insert into DebitCredit values (1,3,1500,'CR')--Payment Credit in Bank AbcBank Account

Insert into Transection values (2,'12/7/2014','Payment Send to Supplier')
insert into DebitCredit values (2,3,1500,'DB')--Payment Debit in Bank AbcBank Account
insert into DebitCredit values (2,2,1500,'CR')--Payment Credit in Supplier Mike Account
```

I purchased some item from supplier 'Mike' amount of invoice is 5000, Amount is credit on Mike then I sale item to Alicia for 1500, Amount Debit to Alicia.

In transaction table, I receive amount 1500 from Alicia, the amount 1500 now debit to Alicia Account and receive amount credit to abcbank.

Now In transaction table, I send amount 1500 to Mike, the amount 1500 now Credit to Mike Account and debit  to abcbank.

Result may be like this

```
Account_Name | Debit | Credit | Balance
Mike-----------1500-----5000----3500
Alicia---------1500-----1500----0
Abcbank---------1500-----1500----0
```

Kindly help me

Thanks

Comment: It's `'Transaction'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rework your table model to make more sense. I ngeneral you only need one Transaction table. YOu also should - and often are legally required to - keep a running number AND the total post transaction,. Helps a ton with performance.

You seem to avoid having account categories with having tons of tables - one for every account category. And you seem to think that a model where everything is calculated on demand will scale above a minimal example level.

Comment: Can you please guide me to create table structure?

Comment: Yes. As consulting job. This is a Q&A site and the answer to  that is: too broad. But you couldr ead the Data Model Resource Book, vol. 1, which also handles tis standard thing called accounting.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
       al.Account_id,
        SUM(CASE Status WHEN 'DB' THEN al.AMOUNT * -1 WHEN 'CR' THEN al.AMOUNT * 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,
        SUM(CASE WHEN al.Status = 'DB' THEN al.Amount   ELSE 0 END) AS Debit_Amount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN al.Status = 'CR' THEN al.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Credit_Amount
    FROM  [dbo].[DebitCredit]  al
    GROUP  BY Account_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Account_Name, Credit-Debit as Amount from (select distinct Account_Name,
       isnull((select sum(Amount) as Debit from [dbo].[DebitCredit] where Account_ID=DC.Account_ID and Status='DB'),0) as Debit,
       isnull((select sum(Amount) as Credit from [dbo].[DebitCredit] where Account_ID=DC.Account_ID and Status='CR'),0) as Credit
from
       [dbo].[Accounts] a join [dbo].[DebitCredit] DC on a.Account_ID=DC.Account_ID) a
```